# Exif orientation tag returns 0

Tags: android, camera, exif

I am developing a custom camera application and I am facing the following problem. When I try to retrieve an orientation using `ExifInterface`, it always returns 0 (`ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED`). This prevents me from rotating the image to the proper state so it can be displayed correctly.

I use a sample code for setting the camera rotation (method containing this code is called before `startPreview()`):

```
android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
        android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(0, info);

        screenOrientation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getOrientation();


        Log.d(TAG, "Screen orientation: " + screenOrientation);

        screenOrientation = (screenOrientation + 45) / 90 * 90;

        int rotation = 0;

        if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            rotation = (info.orientation - screenOrientation + 360) % 360;
        } 
        else{  
            //back-facing camera
            rotation = (info.orientation + screenOrientation) % 360;
            Log.d("Test", "Calculated Rotation" + rotation);
        }
        params.setRotation(rotation);

        camera.setParameters(params);
```

The way I save the taken picture:

```
@Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        File photoFileDir = getFileDir();

        if (!photoFileDir.exists() && !photoFileDir.mkdirs()){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Cannot create directory for the taken picture", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        String pictureName = "photo_" + getPictureDate() + ".jpg";
        String picturePath = photoFileDir.getPath() + File.separator + pictureName;

        File pictureFile = new File(picturePath);

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            try {
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();

                sendPictureSavedBroadcast(context, picturePath);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Picture saved!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Picture could not be saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

The way I try to retrieve the picture orientation:

```
public static int getRotation(String absolutePath){
        try{

            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(absolutePath);

            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, -1);

            Log.d(TAG, "Toolkit, orientation: " + orientation);

            switch(orientation){

                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Image is properly rotated");
                    return 0;

                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    return 90;

                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                    return 180;

                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:

                    return 270;

                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error getting orientation");
                    return -1;

                default:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error getting orientation");
                    return -1;
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return -1;

    }
```

I went through all the similar topics on stackoverflow, but did not find the solution. I would appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: Have you solved this issue ?

Comment: I mean a found a way, but nothing special, works just on some devices.