# Image getting reversed : Android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-bitmap

I tried to capture image using surface view and saved it in a folder. Now when i view the image in imageview, the image showing is reversed. How can i see the image without getting reversed. Any suggestions Please..........

This is a part of code..

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
    surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceview);
    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);


    rawCallback = new PictureCallback() 
    {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)
        {
            Log.d("Log", "onPictureTaken - raw");
        }
    };

    shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback()
    {
        public void onShutter() {
            Log.i("Log", "onShutter'd");
        }
    };

    jpegCallback = new PictureCallback()
    {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) 
         {

            Intent imageIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Asw/Raw Image");
            imagesFolder.mkdirs(); 
            Date d = new Date();
            CharSequence s  = DateFormat.format("MM-dd-yy hh-mm-ss", d.getTime());
            name = s.toString() + ".jpg";
            File output = new File(imagesFolder, name);
            callname = "/sdcard/"Asw/RawImage/" + name;

            Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(output);
            imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);

            OutputStream imageFileOS;

            try {
                imageFileOS = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uriSavedImage);

                ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(name);
                int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt( ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

                switch (orientation) {
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                    rotate = 270;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                    rotate = 180;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    rotate = 90;
                    break;
                }
               // Log.v(Common.TAG, "Exif orientation: " + orientation);
                Log.d("Fragment", "EXIF info for file " +name+ ": " + rotate);

                imageFileOS.write(data);
                imageFileOS.flush();
                imageFileOS.close();

                } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
                {
                e.printStackTrace();
                } 
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("Fragment", "Could not get EXIF info for file " + name+ ": " + e);
            } 
            finally
            {}
            Log.d("Log", "onPictureTaken - jpeg");


            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(callname);

            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);//Displaying raw Image
```

logcat

```
 12-12 16:04:13.678: D/SurfaceView(1631): pckname = com.example.imaging
 12-12 16:04:13.808: D/ViewRootImpl(1631): pckname = com.example.imaging
 12-12 16:04:13.928: I/dalvikvm(1631): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
 12-12 16:04:13.928: I/dalvikvm(1631): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
 12-12 16:04:13.998: D/libEGL(1631): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
 12-12 16:04:14.008: D/libEGL(1631): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
 12-12 16:04:14.008: D/libEGL(1631): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
 12-12 16:04:14.038: D/OpenGLRenderer(1631): Enabling debug mode 0
 12-12 16:04:23.048: I/Log(1631): onShutter'd
 12-12 16:04:23.048: D/Log(1631): onPictureTaken - raw
 12-12 16:04:23.118: E/JHEAD(1631): can't open '/sdcard/Asw/Raw Image/12-12-13 04-04-23.jpg'
 12-12 16:04:23.148: D/Log(1631): onPictureTaken - jpeg
 12-12 16:04:23.188: D/dalvikvm(1631): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 122K, 4% free 5912K/6151K, paused 39ms
 12-12 16:04:23.208: I/dalvikvm-heap(1631): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.453MB for 614416-byte allocation
 12-12 16:04:23.258: D/dalvikvm(1631): GC_CONCURRENT freed 6K, 5% free 6505K/6791K, paused 2ms+2ms
 12-12 16:04:23.348: D/dalvikvm(1631): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 32K, 5% free 6474K/6791K, paused 66ms
 12-12 16:04:23.348: I/dalvikvm-heap(1631): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.587MB for 1228816-byte allocation
 12-12 16:04:23.418: D/dalvikvm(1631): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 5% free 7674K/8007K, paused 3ms+2ms
 12-12 16:04:29.368: D/dalvikvm(1631): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6K, 4% free 7714K/8007K, paused 44ms
 12-12 16:04:29.368: I/dalvikvm-heap(1631): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.212MB for 614416-byte allocation
 12-12 16:04:29.438: D/dalvikvm(1631): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 4% free 8314K/8647K, paused 2ms+2ms
 12-12 16:04:29.468: D/ViewRootImpl(1631): pckname = com.example.imaging
 12-12 16:04:31.358: D/OpenGLRenderer(1631): Flushing caches (mode 0)
  12-12 16:04:31.428: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(1631): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
 12-12 16:04:31.908: D/OpenGLRenderer(1631): Flushing caches (mode 1)
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/20480741/2556111

Answer (score 0):

try this code, Hope it help you.

```
int rotate = 0;
                try {
                    getContentResolver().notifyChange(imageUri, null);
                    File imageFile = new File(imagePath);
                    ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(
                            imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                            ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

                    switch (orientation) {
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                        rotate = 270;
                        break;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                        rotate = 180;
                        break;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                        rotate = 90;
                        break;
                    }
                    Log.v("***TAG***", "Exif orientation: " + orientation);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: i have edited the code....i added this code...bt its not working...can u please verify the code

Comment: In onPictureTaken method where the images are saved after capturing the image

Comment: Common.TAG is just a string

Comment: When i add this line Log.v(Common.TAG, "Exif orientation: " + orientation); Common is not resolved....

Comment: As i told you its a string you can put any string here any like i update my solution.

Comment: its error free..but the image is not rotated :-( something is missing

Comment: can you verify your log, what value you are getting for Exif orientation: " + orientation

Comment: i have added the logcat error...in log one error is shown dat it cant open the "/sdcard/Asw/Raw Image"..this is the file path