# Some Images are rotated in gallery android

Tags: java, android, image, rotation, gallery

Hello i´m using this library: https://github.com/luminousman/MultipleImagePick

I have a problem when i see my images in the multipleimagepick gallery some images looks like are rotated, this problem is with some samsung and motorola devices.

Can anyone help me ?

This library is great !

Thanks !

Comment: That is due to the EXIF tag that is being ignored by the device. You have to rotate it yourself. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20478765/how-to-get-the-correct-orientation-of-the-image-selected-from-the-default-image

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, i want to implement Exif option in all images that i see in the customgallery the solutions that i have found are for only one image.

Comment: Then iterate and apply that process in all your Images. It is the only solution because the orientation value could be different in each image.