# Android front camera images are being saved upside down

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, orientation

I am building an android application that uses the camera capabilities.  The issue I am having is the image data (byte[]) that I get from the front camera comes back upside down on my samsung s7 and nexus phone. It appears correct in the preview, but after I save the data as is and then display the images in a gallery they are all upside down. I know I can just flip the image data before saving but I have tested the code on a blu C 5.0 HD running 4.4 (kitkat) and the image data on that phone comes in oriented the right way. So alwyas flipping the image will cause the error on other devices. I am told the issue is because when the new samsung and nexus phones are built, the front facing cameras are built upside down to save room.  I am not sure if this is correct,but if so, if I flip all images it will mess up the phones that have the correct orientation of the camera.  So is there a way to detect the orientation of the image data before saving the image?

Here is the code I am using:

```
mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
```

Callback:

```
private final Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        processCameraCallback(data);
    }
};
```

Processing Data:

```
    public void processCameraCallback(byte[] data) {
    confirmPhoto(true);
    //Make a new empty picture file
    try {
        pictureFile = Utils.createImageFile();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // Error occurred while creating the File
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to create photo file: " + ex.toString());
        confirmPhoto(false);
        return;
    }

    //Write the file to the storage
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos;
        if (pictureFile != null) {

            fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
        confirmPhoto(false);
        return;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
        confirmPhoto(false);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue with an S7 using the native camera app, also compensating for the orientation returned in the EXIF data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this code to adjust camera orientation:

```
private  int detectCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity,
                                            Camera.CameraInfo info) {

    int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
            .getRotation();
    int degrees = 0;
    switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
    }

    int result;
    if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
        result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
    } else {  // back-facing
        result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
    }
   return result;
}
```

This is from camera api sample and works correctly on nexus 5x.(with upside down camera)

after that just call
`camera.setDisplayOrientation(displayOrientation);`
and it will save picture correctly.

Comment: that code is detecting whether or not the entire phone is rotated.  My issue is that if I take a normal upriht image with the front facing camera the image data, is coming back with the image upside down.  I have the samsung s7 edge and the nexus 5, both having that issue.  I also have a blu C 5.0 HD running 4.4 (kitkat) and the image data on that phone comes in oriented the right way.

Comment: this code is setting proper rotation of camera image based on phone rotation. Compensating camera upside-down position. Have you tried it? If yes and it hasn't work - ok... If not - your comment seems strange. Camera orientation itself is in the `cameraInfo.orientation` field, if you need only it.

Comment: Sorry, I did try your solution and it did not fix it.

Comment: camera.setDisplayOrientation only fix the problem in preview, but images are still saved in the wrong orientation.

Comment: Yes, this is hardware dependent thing. Look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20478765/how-to-get-the-correct-orientation-of-the-image-selected-from-the-default-image
afaik if image is saved in wrong orientation, it should write proper exif tag.