# Multiple Image Crop Android

Tags: android, image, listview, android-gallery

I am making an application that allows the user to upload multiple images from the gallery. The user selects the photos and they are displayed in a list view and the user clicks an upload button. It was working fine until i discovered some images were changing orientation on the list view and on upload. 
I asked around about the issue and someone told me that i had to allow for cropping before upload. Should i make the user crop every selected image from gallery or how should i go about it?

```
if (requestCode == SELECT_MULTIPLE_PHOTOS) {

        String imagesArray = data.getStringExtra(EXTRA_SELECTED_PHOTOS);//get Intent data

        //Convert string array into List by splitting by ',' and substring after '[' and before ']'
        List<String> selectedImages =
                Arrays.asList(imagesArray.substring(1, imagesArray.length() - 1)
                        .split(", "));

        Log.d(TAG, "Selected images is " + selectedImages.size());

        mPhotosPathList = new ArrayList<String>(selectedImages);

        Log.d(TAG, "Selected images path is " + mPhotosPathList.size());


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the image orientation. If it is not in the correct orientation, the get the correct orientation, Try this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20478765/how-to-get-the-correct-orientation-of-the-image-selected-from-the-default-image)