# The bitmap's orientation changes when I use bitmap.copy()

Tags: android, kotlin, imageview, android-bitmap

I'm taking a picture, saving it as a file and displaying it as you can see the main `imageView`, then I use :

```
val filteredImage = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888,true)
```

I use this `filteredImage` variable to apply a filter on the image since it's now mutable.

the problem is: as you can see in the small images bellow the orientation changes and I searched a lot but I couldn't find any solution.

[image: Image From the App]

When I replace the main `ImageView`'s bitmap with the copied one I got this :

[image: The main <code>ImageView</code>'s bitmap orientation changed]

Comment: How do you show image in ImageView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You original image may have Exif orientation data, which are lost on bitmap.copy().

```
@Override
public void onPictureTaken(CameraView cameraView, byte[] data) {
            // Find out if the picture needs rotating by looking at its Exif data
            ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
            int orientation = exifInterface.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);
            int rotationDegrees = 0;
            switch (orientation) {
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    rotationDegrees = 90;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                    rotationDegrees = 180;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                    rotationDegrees = 270;
                    break;
            }
            // Create and rotate the bitmap by rotationDegrees
}
```

Look at this for details:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20480741/1159507

Comment: I'm sorry I wrote it wrong. I need the bitmap to be mutable not immutable as I first wrote. the answer you suggested is pretty good and now I know how to keep the orientation, but the createBitmap used returns immutable bitmap which I can't apply my filter on.